# spring boot maven jar execute order not the same

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm testing Spring OAuth2. I want to deploy it to docker. My container is using OpenJDK 8. After running the `mvn` command in docker, it created a Spring Boot jar file, whereas after I run it by `java -jar xxx.jar`, the Spring Boot behavior is not the same as in Eclipse.

For example, in my laptop:

there are two methods in the same class AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.java

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    xxxxxxx
}
```

runs before

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices defaultAuthorizationServerTokenServices() {
  return endpoints.getDefaultAuthorizationServerTokenServices();
}
```

Whereas in the docker jar:

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices defaultAuthorizationServerTokenServices() {
  return endpoints.getDefaultAuthorizationServerTokenServices();
}
```

Runs before

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    xxxxxxx
}
```

I don't know why exist the difference?
How to make the docker jar like the same as in the laptop?

I build it use spring-boot-maven.

Comment: If ordering is important then make this explicit else different environments (OS, JDK etc) might impact the order of how things are initialized. However looks like you are using some singleton to do stuff instead of letting Spring configure things.